# Internal Javascript not recognized in Asp.net using c# but recogonized in Vb.net

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

I do something like this in Asp.net under c#

```
<script  type="text/javascript" runat="server">
    function hi()
       {}
</script>
```

Even the keyword "function" is not recogonized.But when I do the same using VB.net it's working fine. I am using Visual Studio 2012 Ultimate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the runat="server" attribute.

Do you really need it?

Comment: Thank you very much mate... it worked.. Can you please tell me what happened?

Comment: By adding the runat="server" you are using server side code inside the script tags, to use javascript you have to remove the runat="server"

Comment: Thank you mate :) Saved me from my boss ;)